# add directory to classpath in runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, classpath, spring-boot

In my current spring project, when I run the application, it's created a directory on the user's home directory where I store some configuration files (*.properties file). In my code, I refer to this file in that way:

```
private String getFilename() {
    return System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+".webapp"+File.separator+"webapp.preferences";
}
```

which allows me run the application in any operational system without change the code. I need add this directory to the classpath of the application, to allow me use the annotation `PropertySource` to access the properties stored in the file using either the method getproperty from Enviroment class or the `Value` annotation.

I using spring-boot, so the start point for the application it's that:

```
@Controller
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(value="com.spring")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I also have classes WebAppInitializer, WebAppConfig and DispatcherConfig to store the configurations handled by the XML files web.xml and dispatcher-config.xml from spring.

Anyone can tell if this is possible and hor to accomplish that?

**UPDATE**

Following the sugestions in the commentaries, I add to my project this bean:

```
@Bean
static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer property() throws Exception {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    String filename = System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+".webapp"+File.separator+"webapp.preferences";
    File file = new File( filename );
    if(file.exists())
        propertyConfigurer.setLocation( new FileSystemResource( filename ) );
    else {
        if(file.mkdir()) {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( filename );
            fos.close();
            propertyConfigurer.setLocation( new FileSystemResource( filename ) );
        }
    }

    return propertyConfigurer;
}
```

and try use this in my pojo class:

```
@Input(label = "Titulo")
@Property(key = "geral.titulo")
@Value(value = "${geral.titulo}")
private String titulo;
```

but when I create a new instance of this classe, the fields don't receive the value indicated by the annotation. What I am doing wrong? I verify the file and the properties exists in it.

Comment: Why not using an `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and use the local file? http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/

Comment: @Hannes ok, that should be enough, but do you know some example of use using java class instead of xml?